# india : income tax liability on leaves encashment

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

I have changed my job from a govt company to a private company. At the time of final settlement in the govt company, I have got some money as leaves encashment. Am I liable to pay income tax on that.

Answer (score 1):

For Govt Employees receiving Leave Encashment as part of retirement or separation; there is no tax applicable for the leave encashment. Refer [Income Tax](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Tutorials/Retirement-Benefits-Theoretical.pdf)

Comment: But according to section 10AA http://taxguru.in/income-tax/leave-encashment-leave-salary-tax-treatment-sec-1010aa.html this is tax free for govt employees after retirement. But it is nowhere mentioned whether it is taxable or taxfree in case of resignation

Comment: @ArpitAggarwal Sorry you are right. Updated the answer.

Comment: But here its not clearly mentioned whether it is tax free even in case of resignation also.